renderToString runing as Node standalone script
I'm trying to make transpiler to run as stand-alone node script.
// build.js
import esbuild from 'esbuild';
import path from 'path';
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';
import React, { createElement } from 'react';

const params = {
  common: {
    bundle: true,
    format: "esm",
    jsxFactory: 'React.createElement',
    jsxFragment: 'React.Fragment',
  },
  dev: {
    sourcemap: true,
  },
  prod: {
    sourcemap: false,
    minify: true
  }
}

const loader = {
  common: {
  '.js': 'jsx',
  },
  dev: {},
  prod: {}
}


export const build = async (entryPoints, outdir, env="dev") => {
  return await esbuild.build({
    ...params["common"],
    ...params[env],
    entryPoints: entryPoints,
    outdir: outdir,
    write: true,
    loader: {...loader["common"], ...loader[env]},
  })
}

export const make_importer = async (entryPoints, outdir) => {
  const files = entryPoints.map((p) => path.parse(p))
  const output = path.parse(outdir)

  return files.reduce((out, fh, i) => {
    const output = path.join(outdir, `${fh.name}.js`)
    out[fh.name] = {
      import: async () => await import(output),
      path: output
    }
    return out
  }, {})
}

export const generate_ssr = async (entryPoints, outdir, env="dev") => {
  await build(entryPoints, outdir, env)
  const files = await make_importer(entryPoints, outdir)
  return Object.entries(files).map(async ([k,v]) => {
    const component = await v.import()

    \\ HERE LIES THE PROBLEM

    const elem = createElement(component[k], {})
    console.log(elem)
    return renderToString(elem)
  })
}

Can't figure out how to make element with states:
export function Stuff() {
  // const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div className="App">
    </div>
  );
}


With this its OK:
{
  '$$typeof': Symbol(react.element),
  type: [Function: Stuff],
  key: null,
  ref: null,
  props: {},
  _owner: null,
  _store: {}
}
<div class="App"></div>

But when i uncomment useState:
Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

...

[JSE] TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')
[JSE]     at useState2 (file:///static/Stuff.js:1089:29)
[JSE]     at Stuff (file:///static/Stuff.js:1917:61)

...

package.json
{
  "name": "esbuild-core",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Esbuild js builder.",
  "main": "index.ts",
  "type": "module",
  "entry": "./esbuild_core/public/index.tsx",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20.12.10",
    "@types/react": "^18.3",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.3",
    "esbuild": "^0.20.2",
    "react": "^18.3",
    "react-dom": "^18.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.23.0"
  }
}


tsconfig.json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es5",
      "lib": [
        "dom",
        "dom.iterable",
        "esnext"
      ],
      "outDir": "./dist",
      "allowJs": true,
      "skipLibCheck": true,
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
      "strict": true,
      "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
      "module": "esnext",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "resolveJsonModule": true,
      "isolatedModules": true,
      "jsx": "react",
      "strictNullChecks": true,
      "noEmit": false
    }
  }

Please help! I am out of ideas why internal React Dispatcher is null.
Tried some combination of tsconfig ....
But nothing helps. Probably I am doing some dum-ass mistake.
